# Need to override the ribbon assigned to database on access 2007

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I'm a small business owner and I'm very new to Access/VBA programming and in trying to protect my Access 2007 database I created a ribbon that restricts users permissions to forms, reports, etc.

Although I gave myself what I thought were the right permissions (as the Admin user in the Admins group) now, when I log into access, the ribbon I created (or some other setting I must have changed) does not allow the "Access Options" button to be displayed when I click the round Office Button so now I'm unable to continue work on designing the forms, queries, reports, etc.

How can I override the ribbon selected before the database actually opens, after entering my login information? or just please explain how can I get the "Access Options" button to display again?

Getting desperate over here, I've watched all the videos I found and read postings to no avail... Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold Shift when starting the application. It prevents loading forms, ribbons and autoexec macros. Google for "bypass key".

I'd recommend to create at least two ribbon menus: one for development, with system groups and full backstage (File) menu and production, without.

Comment: Thanks Sergey, I tried your suggestion. The problem with that is that although the Access Options buttons does display now when i click it the Current Database options is disabled, so I'm still unable to change the ribbon selection - which BTW I did create two exactly as you described but evidently need to try something different. Any other ideas maybe?

Comment: Sergey! It worked after all... you just need to release the [shift] key to enter the password on the login screen but THEN by pressing again the [shift] key before pressing [enter] I regained access to the full menus. Thanks a million, you've saved me from a whole lots of headaches!

Comment: Yes, password required if database is encrypted. Please accept the answer if you are satisfied.

Comment: Thanks again and I did click the green arrow, hope that is how the answer is shown as accepted.